# Table breaking max-width of 100%

Tags: css, html-table

I have a table with {max-width: 100%} which in Chrome is wider than its parent container `<div class="entry-content">`. I've looked at some Q&A on stackoverflow and not found a solution that works.

The live code is here: http://vivesco-mhf.com.au/test2/ The table in question is below "Current Group Fitness Classes we have on offer" - the fitness class schedule, line 384 of the source code.

[A jsfiddle I couldn't replicate the problem with is here](https://jsfiddle.net/SRD75/w7u67vub/9/). I'd love to see a formal guide on how to approach CSS problems with jsfiddle, so people like me could bother stackoverflow less.. ;-)

HTML:

```
<section id="container" class="two-columns-right">
  <div id="content" role="main">
    <div id="post-4818" class="post-4818 page type-page status-publish hentry">
      <div class="entry-content">
        <table>
          <tbody>
            <tr style="background-color: #333333; color: #ff9900;">
              <td width="10%" style="border-color: #c2c2c2;"></td>
              <td width="18%" style="border-color: #c2c2c2;"><strong><span style="color: #ff9900;">MON</span></strong></td>
              <td width="18%" style="border-color: #c2c2c2;"><strong><span style="color: #ff9900;">TUE</span></strong></td>
              <td width="18%" style="border-color: #c2c2c2;"><strong><span style="color: #ff9900;">WED</span></strong></td>
              <td width="18%" style="border-color: #c2c2c2;"><strong><span style="color: #ff9900;">THUR</span></strong></td>
              <td width="18%" style="border-color: #c2c2c2;"><strong><span style="color: #ff9900;">SAT</span></strong></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td width="10%" style="border-color: #c2c2c2;">&nbsp;<strong>05.30am</strong></td>
              <td width="18%" style="border-color: #c2c2c2;">Cardio Punch<br>
                St. Elizabeth’s Primary School, Hocking</td>
              <td width="18%" style="border-color: #c2c2c2;">FBI-A<br>
                St. Elizabeth’s Primary School, Hocking</td>
              <td width="18%" style="border-color: #c2c2c2;"></td>
              <td width="18%" style="border-color: #c2c2c2;">Cardio Punch<br>
                St. Elizabeth’s Primary School, Hocking</td>
              <td width="18%" style="border-color: #c2c2c2;"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td width="10%" style="border-color: #c2c2c2;">&nbsp;<strong>06.30am</strong></td>
              <td width="18%" style="border-color: #c2c2c2;">FBI-A<br>
                St. Elizabeth’s Primary School<br>
                Hocking</td>
              <td width="18%" style="border-color: #c2c2c2;">Cardio Punch<br>
                St. Elizabeth’s Primary School<br>
                Hocking</td>
              <td width="18%" style="border-color: #c2c2c2;"></td>
              <td width="18%" style="border-color: #c2c2c2;">FBI-A<br>
                St. Elizabeth’s Primary School, Hocking</td>
              <td width="18%" style="border-color: #c2c2c2;"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td width="10%" style="border-color: #c2c2c2;"><strong>07.00am</strong></td>
              <td width="18%" style="border-color: #c2c2c2;"></td>
              <td width="18%" style="border-color: #c2c2c2;"></td>
              <td width="18%" style="border-color: #c2c2c2;"></td>
              <td width="18%" style="border-color: #c2c2c2;"></td>
              <td width="18%" style="border-color: #c2c2c2;">Cardio Punch<br>
                St. Elizabeth’s Primary School, Hocking</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td width="10%" style="border-color: #c2c2c2;">&nbsp;<strong>05.00pm</strong></td>
              <td width="18%" style="border-color: #c2c2c2;"></td>
              <td width="18%" style="border-color: #c2c2c2;"></td>
              <td width="18%" style="border-color: #c2c2c2;">Cardio Punch<br>
                St. Elizabeth’s Primary School, Hocking</td>
              <td width="18%" style="border-color: #c2c2c2;"></td>
              <td width="18%" style="border-color: #c2c2c2;"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td width="10%" style="border-color: #c2c2c2;"><strong>06.00pm</strong></td>
              <td width="18%" style="border-color: #c2c2c2;"></td>
              <td width="18%" style="border-color: #c2c2c2;"></td>
              <td width="18%" style="border-color: #c2c2c2;">FBI-A<br>
                St. Elizabeth’s Primary School, Hocking</td>
              <td width="18%" style="border-color: #c2c2c2;"></td>
              <td width="18%" style="border-color: #c2c2c2;"></td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="secondary" class="widget-area sidey" role="complementary">
    <ul class="xoxo">
      <li id="search-5" class="widget-container widget_search">test sidebar</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</section>
```

CSS:

```
#container.two-columns-right #content {
    width: calc(100% - 310px);
    float: left;
}
#container.two-columns-right #secondary {
    width: 280px;
    float: right;
}
div.post, div.page, .yoyo > li {
    display: block;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 0;
    margin-bottom: 36px;
}
.entry-content {
    max-width: 100%;
}
.entry-content, .entry-summary {
    clear: both;
    padding-top: 8px;
    word-wrap: break-word;
}
#content table {
    max-width: 100%;
    border: 0;
    margin: 0 0px 24px 0;
    text-align: left;
    width: 100%;
    vertical-align: top;
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 0.9em;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
    display: table;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
#content table td {
  word-wrap:break-word;
}
.entry-content, .entry-summary {
    word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

Comment: what is your actual problem

Comment: @Steve your problem is not very clear to me (

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The padding of your `<td>` is too big, so cells are not wide enough to display your content properly. Try to reduce the padding, or reduce the font-size.

You wrote line 892 in style.css :

`#content tr td {
    border-top: 1px solid transparent;
    padding: 6px 24px;
}`

Try to change the padding : `padding: 6px 20px;` or add a font-size : `font-size:15px;`

Comment: You nailed it. Thanks Syborg. I changed it to `padding: 6px;`